# Juntar dados de duas tabelas por chave estrangeira - Rails ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-record

Olá, eu tenho um Model `Comment` que é um belongs_to de `User`, e um Model `Profile` que **também** é um belongs_to de `User`.

Eu consigo acessar os dados de User facilmente através de `Comment.first.user`, por exemplo, mas eu gostaria de acessar `Profile` através do `User`, sem precisar fazer várias Queries.

Tanto profiles, quanto comments possuem uma chave estrangeira `user_id`. Como fazer para os resultados de ambas as tabelas (comments e profiles) saírem na mesma query? Desde já agradeço!

**Update**

Eu tenho o resultado da query User.find(1) que seria

```
id:12 | email: email@gmail.com | password_digest:....
```

E tenho o resultado da query User.find(1).profile, que seria

```
name: João | lastname: Eduardo | user_id: 12
```

Tem como criar um resultado na ActiveRecord com a união dessas duas tabelas?

```
email: emailg@gmail.com | name: João | lastname: Eduardo
```

A outra dúvida, tem como fazer isso com .all, ao invés de .find ou .where ? Tenho pesquisado bastante sobre isso, tentei utilizar o include, e o joins e até agora não consegui. Supostamente tenho que realizar duas queries, mas não tenho certeza.

Comment: Explique melhor adicionando um código, é mais fácil de entender

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na classe "User" você usou o `has_many :comments` e/ou `has_many :profiles` para indicar os dois lados do relacionamento?

Isto te permitiria pegar estas informações de "User" com:

```
> c = Comment.find(1)
> puts c.user
```

Até fazer o inverso para pegar os dados de "Profile" e "Comments":

```
> u = User.find(1)
> u_profile = u.profiles
> u_comments = u.comments
```

E para fazer o relacionamento entre uma classe via outra classe sinalize no modelo usando o "through":

```
belongs_to :profiles, through: :users
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, na verdade gostaria de pegar esses dados através de Comment, algo do tipo Comment.find(1).user.profile (o que não é possível), criar essa corrente. Eu consigo obter o user pelo comment, mas não o profile, que é um Model irmão.

Comment: Além do "has_many" e do "belongs_to" há um sujeito chamado "through", que define o relacionamento entre as tabelas acontece a partir de uma terceira. Não sei se está correto, não conheço como está a tua modelagem, mas seria como colocar em Comment algo como "belongs_to :profiles, through: :users".

Comment: Perfeito. Era isso mesmo que estava faltando, obrigado! Se você puder depois dar um update no seu post com esse `through`. No meu problema também pude usar o método eager_load que diminui o número de queries `@users = User.eager_load(:profile).all`